# Unable to create call adapter crash when Proguard is active

Tags: java, android, proguard, retrofit2

I want to use ProGuard in my project. I activated the option `minifyEnabled`. When I open the activity that uses the library Retrofit2, the app crashes with:

**Unable to create call adapter for interface retrofit2.Call**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.gatafan.mydeen/com.gatafan.mydeen.ActivityPlaces}:
        java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for interface retrofit2.Call
for method i.a
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to create call adapter for interface retrofit2.Call
for method i.a
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.a(Unknown Source)
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.b(Unknown Source)
at retrofit2.ServiceMethod$Builder.a(Unknown Source)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.a(Unknown Source)
at retrofit2.Retrofit$1.invoke(Unknown Source)
at com.gatafan.mydeen.api.$Proxy1.a(Native Method)
at com.gatafan.mydeen.api.VenueManager.requestFoursquare(Unknown Source)
at com.gatafan.mydeen.ActivityPlaces.onCreate(Unknown Source)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Call return type must be parameterized as Call<Foo> or Call<? extends Foo>
        at retrofit2.Utils.e(Unknown Source)
at retrofit2.ExecutorCallAdapterFactory.a(Unknown Source)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.a(Unknown Source)
at retrofit2.Retrofit.a(Unknown Source)
... 21 more
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the github page for Retrofit there is a section explaining what to do when using proguard:

> PROGUARD
>   If you are using Proguard in your project add the following lines to your configuration:

```
-dontwarn retrofit2.**
-keep class retrofit2.** { *; }
-keepattributes Signature
-keepattributes Exceptions
```

try this configuration first, before moving forward with proguard changes

Comment: Wow! Thank you. Sorry for this stupid question, i'm new in Proguard

Comment: @MansurNashaev not a stupid question, proguard can be confusing when first starting out, luckily square usually documents their api's with proguard configuration blocks. Happy Coding!

Comment: @inner_class7 yes but Proguard is really really useful

Comment: I got the minus, so I thought it was too silly. thank you very much, you helped me a lot

Comment: I am getting nullpointerexception after adding above line.Please help on the same issue which I am getting as mentioned in question